# Changing hyperledger-composer resource definition

Tags: hyperledger-composer

So as a project matures it will almost certainly be necessary to modify attributes of the resource definitions to cope with additional requirements.

Let's use two trivial examples - to add a country code to a client address, or to remove a middle initial and swap in a middle name field instead.

Currently if the resource definition changes, composer won't read whatever values are extant in the repository. I didn't exhaustively try all combos, but have had to reconstitute my blockchain at least twice because of this problem.

Is there a way to mark fields either as "new" or "deprecated" to get past this that I overlooked? It will be hard to make a case to move a system that can't be changed forward to production.

In the same vein it doesn't seem to like empty or null strings much (at least for participant attributes). Having an "optional" override somewhere would save a lot of extra bounds checking in my application. Is there one of those I missed too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can use the APIs or REST to expose the legacy data?  You may be referring to Playground above (its not really a tool for looking at production data, its for model prototyping/sandbox/testing type stuff).

On optional question - can just add that the field is optional in the model - example here -> https://github.com/hyperledger/composer-sample-networks/blob/master/packages/pii-network/models/pii.cto#L20

Comment: The optional keyword was the key. Thx.